Jetpack Compose: SwipeToDismiss in Horizontal Pager
Is there a way to make the SwipeToDismiss function work in a HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose? At the moment the Pager consumes all drag gestures so the SwipeToDismiss is not working.
There is a pageNestedScrollConnection parameter in the HorizontalPager composable:
"pageNestedScrollConnection - A NestedScrollConnection that dictates how this Pager behaves with nested lists. The default behavior will see Pager to consume all nested deltas.
pageContent - This Pager's page Composable."
Could this be used to accomplish this?

Please show us the code you have so far.
